# Adding Logout Button to Share Screen in Facebook Connect for iPhone

Tags: iphone, button, facebook, logout, sharekit

I have been playing with Facebook Connect for iPhone, as well as ShareKit. Seems like Facebook Connect will work best for me for now (in case you were going to suggest Sharekit - just beating you to the chase!). But, I am having one difficulty..

I would like to add a 'logout' button to the "Publish this Story" screen (view). I don't want a button on my own view.. this is being called from an action sheet that also has several other sharing options, and I don't want to also have to list a logout option for each service.  I have thought about this long and hard, and the best way for me to do it would be to add a button on "Publish this Story", perhaps up in the facebook header. Does anyone know 1) if this CAN be done and 2) if so, how to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that dialog is served up by Facebook and can't bequeath altered. We had similar needs. We actually decided to offer logout options in Settings instead of from the screen where the sharing options were offered.

Comment: I figured as such and created a logout button on the actionsheet. Thanks for confirming.